# How to do factor analysis when there are multiple data about one objective?

Tags: factor-analysis

20 respondents -> 100 questionnaires(10 identical questions each) about 5 brands

each respondent -> 5 questionnaires(5 brands)

should I preprocess the data(ex. calculate mean base on brands, the new input has only 5 data: brand 1 to 5 data) or should I just do FA straightforward?

btw not asking about coding, just pure stat question.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you have $n=20$ individuals and you asked them $10 \times 5 = 50$ questions each. Are you asking how to do factor analysis on this data? (It seems to me that you have 20 data points in a 50-dimensional space.) What I did not understand is what you aim to do with this information. What is your research question?

Comment: @Ertxiem it s just a homework. there are 5 brands and 20 individuals, each individual get 50 question(10 question * 5 brands, means ask the same question to 5 different brands). my question is all the FA question I have met before is 1 to 1 situation(ex. 10 student with their grades on 5 subjects), not like this one which is like 10 student with their grades on 5 subjects at different times, which mean for every student, their data have been collected multiple times.

Comment: in this case should I just do FA straightforward or do some preprocessing and make the case back to 1 to 1 situation(ex.for each student, calculate the mean of the grades, combine those grades on different time into 1 variable and make it back to 10 student with their processed grade on 5 subjects)?

Comment: my research question is: use FA to identify and label the smallest number of factors that best account for the variance in the data.(the original question is too long, to be short, those questions can be divided into different topics and we have to obtain an good interpret, but i don't think that s the point, the point is what should I do with the raw data to make the answer significative, i mean if I am doing it wrong at first, even if I comes up with a answer, it will not be the right one)

Comment: In that case, I would suggest to use the original, untransformed, data. However, given the low number of individuals, it seems to me that the results will not be trustworthy.

Comment: yes you are 100% right, but actually that question is 6*18(brand*individual) which is even smaller...

Comment: and btw could I ask why should I use the original instead of the preprocess one? should I keep using the original if I ignore the small sample problem?

Comment: Usually, processing the data will remove some of the information it contains. If you use the mean of a set of answers you will be losing some information related with the variance of the individual answers.

Comment: sorry that I didn't mention the data is actually a 7 point scale(questionnaire base) and I am worried about if I am not processing the data at all, the whole thing will become 100 different brands instead of 5 different brands at 20 different observation points.